# Go to link after that video is finished ionic or Angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i hae this video in my Ionic APP

```
<div style="background-color:black" class="video-container">
<video src="img/INTRODUZIONE.mp4?autoplay=0" id="video1" preload="auto|metadata|none" autoplay="true"  frameborder="2" width="440" height="345" allowfullscreen></video>
                </div>
```

I need that after video is finished app move to a given link.

How i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Seeking found a better way, unfortunately I can not try and write a code to show that it works, but you can do this :

Search in [AngularUi](http://angular-ui.github.io/) Event Binder

```
        <video src="img/INTRODUZIONE.mp4?autoplay=0" 
          id="video1" ui-event="{ ended : 'video.stop()'}" preload="auto|metadata|none" autoplay="true"  frameborder="2" width="440" height="345" allowfullscreen>
        </video>
```

In your controller

```
app.controller('VideoCtrl', function ($rootScope){

    var video = this;
    this.stop = function(){
       alert("VIDEO FINISH");
    }

});
```

Comment: Not work form. Where i need to place this code? In ionic view? Or in controller?